# Is there a way to overwrite log files in python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I'm using python2.x logging module, like,

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                filename='logs.log',
                level=logging.INFO)
```

I want my program to overwrite logs.log file for each execution of the script, currently it just appends to old logs. 
I know the below code will overwrite, but if there is a way to do it via logging config, it'll look better.

```
with open("logs.log", 'w') as file:
  pass
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add the `filemode` option to `basicConfig`:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                filename='logs.log',
                filemode='w',
                level=logging.INFO)
```

From the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-level-functions) documentation for the `basicConfig` method (in the big table explaining all options):

> `filemode`:   Specifies the mode to open the file, if filename is specified (if filemode is unspecified, it defaults to ‘a’).

Comment: Note that "filemode" is the keyword "mode" if you use DictConfig.

Example:
`
        "handlers":
            {
                "file":
                    {
                        "class": "logging.FileHandler",
                        "formatter": "form02",
                        "level": "INFO",
                        "filename": "logs.log",
                        "mode": "w", # Overwrite file if it exists
                    },
            },
`

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. 'w' will add truncation line and append the content. Just tested in Python 3.10. Here is documentaion: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer is to add the `filemode = 'w'` AND `force = True` parameter to `basicConfig`. What seems to be happening is that default handlers are setting the filemode to a for append. With filemode already set, logging doesn't bother to apply your requested filemode of  w for write. Adding the force parameter disables all default handlers and uses all the parameters you specified instead.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the correct answer in multiple questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                filename='logs.log',
                filemode='w',
                level=logging.INFO)
```

and

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                filename='logs.log',
                filemode='w+',
                level=logging.INFO)
```

**always append** in Python 2.7, on both Windows and Linux

Comment: I'm also seeing the same behavior in Python 3.6. This just doesn't seem right- I'm passing filemode='w' in all cases.