# Logging to python file doesn't overwrite file when using the mode='w' argument to FileHandler

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have some code to set up a log in Python 2.7 (using the logging module):

```
import os
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_filename=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(copasi_file),os.path.split(copasi_file)[1][:-4]+'_log.log')
handler=logging.FileHandler(log_filename,mode='w')
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.debug('debugging message')
```

This code works and I am getting the output, however I intend to use this log to do a lot of debugging so I want to overwrite the log file each time its run. In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) say to use the `mode` keyword argument to the 'FileHandler`. It doesn't specify precisely *which* mode to use for overwrite file each time but I think a reasonable assumption would be`mode='w'`. This however doesn't work. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. I used the code you provided and just changed the file name, the log is overwritten every time I run the code. If I change `mode` to `a` then new run adds line to end,

Comment: This is strange and may be related to a previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396050/why-does-this-code-for-creating-a-python-log-not-work?noredirect=1#comment64203174_38396050) I had. Do you know if it possible to permanently override the logging modules basic behaviour?

Comment: I don't know a way to do it but it doesn't mean it's impossible,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the file doesn't actually get overwritten until a new python shell is started.

Answer (score 21):

This solves problem for me:

```
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_filename, 'w+')
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with this to much, and I did not really see anything that stuck out in google. Have you tried just using:

```
    handler=logging.FileHandler(log_filename, 'w')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

By this one:

```
logger.handlers=[handler]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (missing force=True)
`The actual answer is to add the filemode = 'w' AND force = True parameter to basicConfig.` from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71259043/2604720